# Is posible to share one domain with many web sites?

Tags: web-hosting

Imagine you have several web sites deployed in different servers.  It's posible to share the main domain?  V.g.:

mydomain.com/site1
mydomain.com/site2
mydomain.com/site3

Comment: Short answer yes, not so short answer, yes, but you'll need something in front, like a proxy, or load balancer.

Comment: I am tempted to downvote this question as being overly vague. I think that it could used a bit of clarification. What is the network scenario? Are we to assume these web servers are all public? By "main domain" do you mean the second-level domain name (eg mydomain.com) or are you willing to consider third-level sub-domain names? Your URL examples show each web site as a sub-folder which is also a valid solution for having multiple public web sites sharing a single second-level domain name. @Apocatastasis, can you elaborate on the question?

Comment: @SunSparc: Don't be tempted, just do it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: yes. It's far far easier to use a subdomain since otherwise you would need a proxy.

To extend on this, suppose you have site1, site2, and site3 on different web servers. Rather than trying to mess with a proxy, simply add a subdomain to your domain like `site1.domain.com` that points to the proper web server.

The more complicated method (if you can't have/don't want subdomains) is to use something like nginx to proxy requests for the specific folders to a remote site. This page has a decent starting point: http://www.kirkdesigns.co.uk/nginx-proxy-apache-access-remote-host-ip-address-using-modpraf

Again, it's much much easier to just add a subdomain.